# Ajax и обработчики jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь разобраться с Ajax, и возникла следующая проблема.
Например, есть разметка

```
<div id='ajax-container'>
  ..
  <div class='some-class-with-handler'>
    ..
  </div>
  ..
</div>
```

При загрузке документа на **.some-class-with-handler** вешается обработчик:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  ..
  $('.some-class-with-handler').click(function(){
    ..
  });
  ..
}
```

Потом в какой-то момент Аяксом перезаполняется всё содержимое **#ajax-container**, но так, что блок **.some-class-with-handler** как бы остаётся на месте. При этом обработчик события с этого блока слетает, и вопрос - как его правильно восстановить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не показали главное - как замещаете контент. Если перезаписываете весь блок, то поможет делегированная обработка:

```
$('#ajax-container').on('click', '.some-class-with-handler', function(){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Контент замещается действительно полностью. Насчёт делегированной обработки понял, спасибо!